# Winter Bash 2019 resources cause a browser warning in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, firefox, winter-bash-2019

When viewing a Stack Exchange page in Firefox 71.0 on macOS 10.15.1, I get three of the following warnings in my browser console. They do not seem to impact the actual behaviour of the site, but they might do in future editions if browsers become more strict in disabling these kind of resources.

> The script from “https://winterbash2019.stackexchange.com/api/current-hats?callback=winterBashCurrentHats4751173&userids=4751173&host=stackoverflow.com&_=1576135405009” was loaded even though its MIME type (“”) is not a valid JavaScript MIME type. [[Learn More]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options)

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Content-Type should now be provided. Warnings should be gone.